# Creating a class to remove special characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'd like to write a class that can remove a special character from any column of a dataframe that I would like. For instance, let's say I have data from a table below:

```
Column A | Column B
?a?      | ?b?
```

I would like to return:

```
Column A | Column B
  a      | b
```

I tried writing a class so I could remove the special character from each column that I choose from my data. For instance, if I want to remove "?" from column A, I want to be able to do that for that specific column.

```
class a():

    def __int__(self, col):
        self.col = col 

    def remove_char(self,col):
        for i, col in enumerate(df.col):
            df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].str.replace('?', '')
        return san_col


p = a()

san_data = p.remove_apost(df)
```

I get an error that states that:

'NameError: name 'san_col' is not defined'

I am newer to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You never define `san_col` in your function and thusly can not return it.

Comment: Why does it need to be a class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never ever define `san_col` variable.

So to solve it, (also make it better):

```
class a:
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df=df
    def remove_char(self):
        return self.df.replace('\?','',regex=True)
```

Then call it like:

```
p = a(df)
print(p.remove_char())
```